# Does downloading the HTML content of a webpage with VBA fire Google Analytics events?

Tags: vba, excel, google-analytics, web-scraping

I'm wondering whether Google Analytics events are fired if I'm scraping data from a webpage using VBA scraping script?  I'm not using browser simulation, I'm using `MSXML2.XMLhttp` object with a `GET` request.

For example

```
Set XMLreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLhttp")
With XMLreq

    url = "url_of_website"
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    Set HTMLdoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText

End With
```

Does this fire Google Analytics data back to the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136682/how-to-disable-javascript-in-mshtml-htmldocument-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `MSXML2.XMLhttp` to download a web page does not trigger Google analytics events, since no JavaScript code is executed this way. But when you then load the web page into the `HTMLDoc` object, JavaScript can be executed and Google analytics events might be triggered depending on how Google Analytics is embedded into the web page.

Comment: OK thanks @NineBerry    So is there any way to parse the downloaded HTML without firing Javascript such as GA?

Comment: You might try the proposal in the linked question to set designMode to "On".